# Finding recurrence relations in combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I'm working my way through basic combinatorics questions with recurrence relation, and can't quite get my head about the right way of solving them.

For example, I have two following examples in my Uni text-book:

1) Strings formed from 0,1,2 characters, needed to calculate amount of possible strings without combinations 00 and 01.

The solution is:
$$f(n)=2f(n-1) + f(n-2)$$ i.e. taking only allowed characters

2) Strings formed from A,B,C characters, needed to calculate amount of possible strings without AB combination.

The solution is:
$$f(n)=3f(n-1) - f(n-2) $$i.e. taking all characters and subtracting the forbidden ones.

The idea is very clear, but what I can't understand is why in first solution only valid cases are taken, and in second case all cases taken then one invalid is subtracted.

It seems that I can solve it in reverse, i.e.:
1) $f(n)=3f(n-1) - 2f(n-1)$ //i.e. 0,1,2 minus 00 and 01 case
2) $f(n)=2f(n-1)+2f(n-2)$ //i.e. B,C + AA,AC case

But when translated to difference equations, the results are different.

Anything I'm missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: If I'm not misreading your argument, you need to argue differently. It isn't just one case of $AB$, say. If at step $n$, you end your string with $A$, there are 8 3-strings at the end of the length $n$ string that are valid; but only $5$ such 3-strings. These tie the last 3 steps of your selection together.  As you say, you can add $3 \cdot f(n-1)$, then need to subtract something - those are the ones ending $BB, BC$ in the last 2 steps, which then relate back somehow to $n-2$. Or this is how it seems to me. There is something more elegant which eludes me (I assume order matters).

Comment: Typos: only 5 such 3-strings ending with $B$ in step $n$. And it's $BB, CB$, not $BB, BC$ as I write above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 1), "02" is an allowable length-2 string, and $002$ is not an allowable length-3 string. Your formula
$$3f(n-1)-2f(n-2)$$
is "double-subtracting" the string "$00\,02$", since it is *not* counted by $3f(n-1)$, but *is* counted by $2f(n-2)$.

The correct formulation would be to subtract all the string beginning with either "01" or "002":
$$f(n) = 3f(n-1) - f(n-2) - f(n-3)$$
which you can check is equivalent to the book's answer.

In 2), "BB" is an allowable length-2 string, while "$AA\,BB$" is not. But $2f(n-2)$ is counting the latter.

There is no simple additive formulation, since there are infinitely many valid prefixes: $B, C, AC, AAC, AAAC, \ldots.$

You could, however, count string beginning with $B, C, AA,$ or $AC$, and then subtract the invalid strings beginning with $AAB$, yielding

$$f(n) = 2f(n-1) + 2f(n-2) - f(n-3).$$

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation!